# How do I have two perspective views for sculpting?

Tags: sculpting

I am learning to sculpt in Blender and I ran into an annoying problem. The problem is that when I move the mouse, the tool moved in parallel to the screen. I was hoping that quad view would solve the problem. But you can have only one perspective view there. How do I sculpt working with different views seen from slightly different angles?

Comment: I have tried menu / Window / New Main Window and seeing sculpting from two different perspectives side by side. It is almost what I want but the problem is the other window is updated only when I lift the finger off the mouse. I there a way of having a live preview form the other angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your mouse as on the picture below (on this narrow black line between viewport and editor type) and right click:
[image]

than you can choose between horizontal or vertical split and left click on the place where you want to split your viewport
[image]

now you can scuplt in both areas :)

Comment: there is a place on that line where you do not get the options. That < symbol on the edge of the screen when hovered also displays <==> but with the options to split the screen. That is why I was confused. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.6.2, press spacebar to start animation playback, and start sculpting. Ctrl+Alt+Q to view in quad mode. All viewports update in real time.